# android - setBackground with checking android version not working

Tags: android, button, background, drawable

I want change the background drawable of a button. My min. SDK version is 14. Therefore I check the current version, which is installed on the device:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    buttonClubPublic.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonClubPublic.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_button));
    buttonClubPrivate.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonClubPrivate.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uncheck_button));
} else {
    buttonClubPublic.setBackground(buttonClubPublic.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.check_button));
    buttonClubPrivate.setBackground(buttonClubPrivate.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uncheck_button));
}
```

When the current version is equal or above 16 I use `setBackground` otherwise I use `setBackgroundDrawable`.

However, it seems that Eclipse doesn't recognize the if/else check of the version, because I get an error:

> Error: Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14)

I set the button in XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/create_club3_club_privat"
    android:text="@string/create_club3_privat"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/check_button_size"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/check_button_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/uncheck_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/create_team_check_button_margin"
/>
```

Comment: Is the button background dynamic or could you just set it in XML?

Comment: Did you add the support library? If the answer is YES, then it's only a WARNING (yellow, not red), you can suppress it.

Comment: i set the button in xml

Comment: If you set the button in the xml, there's perfectly no need to reset it in code.

Comment: you need a @SuppressLint 'NewApi' annotation

Comment: in this class i don't include the support library. Should I do that?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use higher features on lower devices, your PROJECT (it's not a per-class feature) should include the support library.

Comment: Sry I forgot the function. I set different button in xml, when I click on one button, the button style should change, and I change it with a background drawable.

Comment: OK, add the support library, suppress the warning and you're ready to go.

Comment: but why should I include the support library? I dont use any function of it. When the device running on api level 16 or higher then I use setBackground and when its below I use setBackgroundDrawable

Comment: ok @SuppressLint 'NewApi' work. Thanks a lot!