# Getting "no method with name='setBackground'" upon changing .Background property on legacy Android versions (<4.1)

Tags: android, xamarin

Getting,

> no method with `name='setBackground'` *signature*

or

> no method with `name='setBackground'`

upon changing `.Background` property (to change the background visuals) in the app running on legacy Android versions (<4.1)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this question about Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549550) suggests, `setBackground` is problematic on API below level 16. Unlike covered in the question though, to work around the issue *AND* have your code Android 4.0-compatible, you'd want to change your background with the following (reproducible logic)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)
{
    layout.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
}
else
{
    layout.Background = gd;
}
```